# The box model - why does not the yellow box stay inside?

Tags: html, css

I have two rows:

```
<div>
    The first row
</div>
<div>
    The <span class="boxed">second</span> row
</div>
```

The word "second" is in a yellow box with padding:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
div { border: 1px solid black; }
.boxed {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

As you can see I am using the border-box model. But the yellow box does not. Or does it?

I expected the second row to be as high as the yellow box, but that did not happen. There is no float, no CSS `position`, but still the yellow box overflows the div. How can I make the second div row contain the yellow box inside of it?

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/9xEgA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline boxes are not affected by `box-sizing` since they are never affected by the `width` and `height` properties. When you add padding to inline boxes, all that does is cause their backgrounds to expand, pushing only their left and right edges away from surrounding content, but not their top and bottom edges (since the line height is not altered). That's why it overflows. See sections [10.6.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced) and [10.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) of the spec for more details.

If you want to [hide the overflow](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9xEgA/3), use `overflow: hidden`:

```
div { border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; }
```

Otherwise, if you want to make the second row expand to contain the yellow box, you might be able to make the yellow box `display: inline-block` [without any adverse side-effects](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9xEgA/4):

```
.boxed {
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I still do not understand why `inline-block` is needed though.

Comment: @Leo: That's because an inline-block is formatted as a block container for all its contents, and this block container is then taken as a whole and laid inline. An inline element, on the other hand, is just text; there is no real block "container" to speak of.

Comment: That is a good mnemonic, but it looks like a strange W3C decision to me. I mean the inline span still have height and width even if you can not set them directly. Those definition both open for surprises and -- a bit more flexibility. Maybe the flexibility was the win in the decision? (Many thanks for the links. Perhaps one day I will understand the structure of the W3C documents. ;-) )

Comment: @Leo: "the inline span still have height and width even if you can not set them directly" It doesn't really - it completely depends on its inline contents (even inline-blocks do not affect inline-level height calculations). All I can say is that it's pretty complicated :)

Comment: I see. I guess I will have more surprises. :-) Without the good help here it would take a lot of time before I could resolve these surprises. I would be trapped in doubt of browser bugs and W3C decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: block` to the span. Inline block elements sometimes alter the document flow in strange ways when you do things like add padding to them. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xEgA/2/)

Comment: Thanks, Josh. `inline-block` works (but `block`does a bit too much). The span has `display:inline` by default here. So `display:inline` does not respect the block-sizing model. A surprise, but I guess there is an explanation to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **display: inline-block** property for your .boxed span.

```
.boxed {
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xEgA/1/)